# Verifying Auth0 JWT throws invalid algorigthm

Tags: node.js, oauth, jwt, auth0, rs256

I have created an Auth0 client, I am logging in and receive this token:

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ik1rVkdOa1l5T1VaQ1JqTkRSVE5EUmtNeU5rVkROMEUyUTBVMFJrVXdPVEZEUkVVNU5UQXpOZyJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3RvdGFsY29tbW56LmF1LmF1dGgwLmNvbS8iLCJzdWIiOiJnb29nbGUtb2F1dGgyfDEwMzI5NzA4OTYyMTk5NjUwMjY2MiIsImF1ZCI6ImxTWUtXMUZZdENkMWJLQmdXRWN0MWpCbmtDU3R2dW5SIiwiaWF0IjoxNTA5ODYyMTI1LCJleHAiOjE1MTAyMjIxMjV9.kjmckPxLJ4H9R11XiBBxSNZEvQFVEIgAY_jj2LBy4sEJozBB8ujGE7sq9vEIjMms-Lv2q9WzFQPrqcxyBcYC4Je4QojMgvqLDCodtpot0QUle8QfGmonc1vZYIZyX-wqyOXtRqhoZVEKTeLhm9Le2CV4_a3BwgjkE1LjcDx01GZfsnaId8mh10kGk-DBmr5aVc8MxglLCq5Uk8Zbl2vDc__UMDgx1eQPQg-zve4fUf8zHcxizypYTnF_v0dEAT00L2j5J41SFYdWvP6ReQ3vhVYew2o9iM6u1s75HE-xW8s4pzV4BZAQtgfgIeCd6aVGZs76bcnQXBLej1B7zaPBvA
```

What I am trying to do now is to verify the token using [jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken). The token is signed with an *RS256* algorithm.

I downloaded the signing certificate as a `.pem` and I am **successfully** using it to verify the token like this:

```
var cert = fs.readFileSync('certificate.pem');
jwt.verify(token, cert, {algorithm: 'RS256'}, (err, decoded) => {
  console.log(err)
  console.log(decoded)
});
```

What I want to do and it doesn't work is verifying the token using the secret (which is called *Client Secret* in the Auth0 client settings and is a string).

```
jwt.verify(token, MYSECRET, {algorithm: 'RS256'}, (err, decoded) => {
  console.log(err)
  console.log(decoded)
});
```

This code always throws an error:

```
{ JsonWebTokenError: invalid algorithm
    at Object.module.exports [as verify] (C:\code\aws\learn-authorizer\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:90:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\code\aws\learn-authorizer\testme.js:25:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:665:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3 name: 'JsonWebTokenError', message: 'invalid algorithm' }
```

My question is: how can I verify the RS256 token using the secret key as opposed to using the certificate file? (I also tried creating a new client which is using the HS256 algorithm, but I get the same error).

Comment: Try Updating Your jwt module.

Comment: @AkshitGrover I use the latest version already

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are using *only* a secret key then using RS256 won't work, as it's based on a private/public key pair. Using only a secret key usually indicates H256. In my answer I assume that what you call `MYSECRET` is just the content of `certificate.pem`.

Anyways, I would assume your string has to contain

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

and

```
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

or *PUBLIC* instead of *PRIVATE*.

You can see this in [source](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/blob/master/verify.js#L90). The lines mentioned in your error message contains:

```
if (!~options.algorithms.indexOf(header.alg)) {
  return done(new JsonWebTokenError('invalid algorithm'));
}
```

and `options.algorithms` is defined as

```
if (!options.algorithms) {
  options.algorithms = ~secretOrPublicKey.toString().indexOf('BEGIN CERTIFICATE') ||
                       ~secretOrPublicKey.toString().indexOf('BEGIN PUBLIC KEY') ?
                        [ 'RS256','RS384','RS512','ES256','ES384','ES512' ] :
                       ~secretOrPublicKey.toString().indexOf('BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY') ?
                        [ 'RS256','RS384','RS512' ] :
                        [ 'HS256','HS384','HS512' ];

}
```

If you don't have the RSA things at the start and end it will look for the following algorithms: `'HS256','HS384','HS512'`.

I haven't used RS256 with JWT before, but I have used it with ssh, and I know that it's very sensitive to having the header. The string has to be in the exactly correct format.

Comment: I want to stress the value of this sentence "...it's very sensitive to having the header. The string has to be in the exactly correct format."
It is indeed extremely sensitive, it cost me a day of work.

Answer (score 9):

You need to specify the allowed [`algorithms`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken#jwtverifytoken-secretorpublickey-options-callback) as an Array of Strings, instead of an `algorithm` String.

```
jwt.verify(token, MYSECRET, { algorithms: ['RS256'] });
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the third parameter of your verify method which is

```
{algorithm: 'RS256'} to ==>{algorithms: 'RS256'}
```

and make sure you write the correct name for the algorithm, It will work fine

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the algorithm to "HS256"?

According to the Auth0 docs at https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/verify-access-token#verify-the-signature

```
For HS256, the API's Signing Secret is used. You can find this information at your API's Settings. Note that the field is only displayed for APIs that use HS256.

For RS256, the tenant's JSON Web Key Set (JWKS) is used. Your tenant's JWKS is https://YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN/.well-known/jwks.json.
```

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on this too !!

**problem**:

- decode was able to give us visibility into the JWT
- but we needed to verify the signature of the token

**steps** in the following code:

1. we decode the token (using [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken))
2. we get the domain from token
3. we get JSON file which has the well-known/jwks using this domain
4. JWKS can be more than one, we get the same key from JWKS which is in our decoded token header
5. we use [node-jose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-jose) package which calls verifies the signature
6. you can test on your local via repo: https://github.com/AkberIqbal/auth0-jwt-verify-signature-javascript-nodejs

```js
const verifyJWT = async (token, verifyURL) => {

    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const result = jwt.decode(token, { complete: true });

    const domainFromToken = result?.payload?.iss;

    const signatureUrl = verifyURL ? verifyURL : `${domainFromToken}.well-known/jwks.json`;

    const jwksResponse = await axios.get(signatureUrl).catch((exp)=>{
        console.log('Error getting jwkResponse:', exp);
        reject(false)
    });

    const jwks = jwksResponse?.data?.keys;
    console.log('# of JWKS:', jwks.length, ' -trying to find:', result?.header?.kid);

    const relevantKey = jwks.filter(jk => jk.kid === result?.header?.kid)[0];
    console.log('relevantKey:', relevantKey);

    const algoForImport = selectedKey.alg
    const publicKey = await jose.importJWK(relevantKey, algoForImport);

     const { payload, protectedHeader }  = await jose.jwtVerify(token, publicKey, {
            iss: 'issuer, get this from decoded token, or the issuer you expect',
        }).catch(exp => {
            console.log('exp:', exp);
            reject(exp);
        });

    if (payload && Object.keys(payload).length > 0) {
        console.log('Object.keys(payload):', Object.keys(payload));
        // uncomment to take a closer look
        // console.log('joseResult:', joseResult);
        resolve('ok');
    }

    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**hello maybe you are missing utf8 flag, this works on [jsonwebtoken 9](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken/v/9.0.1)**

```
const fs = require('fs')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

const private_key = fs.readFileSync('secret/private.key', 'utf8')
const public_key = fs.readFileSync('secret/public.pem', 'utf8')

const token = jwt.sign({
    data: 'data'
}, private_key, { algorithm: 'RS256' })

const verified = jwt.verify(token, public_key, { algorithms: 'RS256'})
```