# Verify Auth0 JWT with Node

Tags: node.js, jwt

Im getting a JWT from Auth0. I can decode it with the following middleware function on my Node server (using https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-node)

```
function authoriseToken(req, res, next) {
  const token = req.headers.authorization.replace('Bearer ', '');
  const decodedToken = jwt.decode(token);
  console.log('decodedToken ', decodedToken);
  next();
}
```

How can I verify the token? I keep getting an error `JsonWebTokenError: invalid algorithm`

```
function authoriseToken(req, res, next) {
  const token = req.headers.authorization.replace('Bearer ', '');
  const verifyedToken = jwt.verify(token, "my-secrete");
  console.log('verifyedToken ', verifyedToken);
  next();
}
```

Im not sure if I should be using a secrete or a jwksUri or what the difference is

Here is the actual token:

eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ik16QkJRa1k0T0RRNE9VWTJORVZGT1VJNFFrSXpNRUZDT0RaQ01VSTBOVGN4TWpVeU1UYzNRdyJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL25vbWFkZ3JvdXBzLmF1dGgwLmNvbS8iLCJzdWIiOiJhdXRoMHw1YjMxMDhkNjc4NzFkNTBkZTA0Njc2NWEiLCJhdWQiOiJTZkQyMEVPZVdRbHlnWXIwUHNXODdtYjd0OGFBOFI2NiIsImlhdCI6MTUzMDAxMzQwMCwiZXhwIjoxNTMwMDQ5NDAwLCJhdF9oYXNoIjoiUi1mRGc3SVRzUUdqemplX3VUR01RdyIsIm5vbmNlIjoiQnN-VmZxNzdtNERuaTJ1LjlIUVJlSEpzeHA4UjF2aDcifQ.CwZb6j3DshbD5M-OWBQpc10EIpAd3D-TuZTA1p7alePobSRVM7bE9Yzr5DIRyc2YUQZQ_OBwVLfFPq0pEBTWFYq2O43FJZ726xP1zK7Ty4PvAoLe4Cx6E0Ow8V8Ymo87XCIKX8J1ndg47q5glKzsnSMToutEWRZ2lnxJyirD4m4EwFykDF8DalA1sWvqnYXEwWraY3VLroqyZH2nkeLDcpcMdJ0tWwmzldwi7ym9OmegV5GBl7F6BgrZNIJfdoT88Rs4AKzogJyJuVQ1XlD7Up_nYlAKBmRMgkFt3t_4iq7pTkgdrWl1tXuJQsnmkkVH6_yffNYrWDnuirWwTCG4XQ

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Verifying Auth0 JWT throws invalid algorigthm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119043/verifying-auth0-jwt-throws-invalid-algorigthm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[verify](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#jwtverifytoken-secretorpublickey-options-callback) takes `algorithms` option in third parameter, adjust value with the correct one.

You can find it under applications > advanced settings > oauth > JsonWebToken Signature Algorithm

Comment: My algorithm is RS256. Ive added this as a 3rd parameter but I get the same error: { algorithm: 'RS256' },

Comment: For RS256 you need the certificate, you can fin it at `https://your-tenant.auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json` see https://auth0.com/blog/navigating-rs256-and-jwks/

Comment: The certificate is present in advanced setting second last tab.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Gabriel Bleu's answer here is my complete code:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const pemCert = `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
// <<CERT CODE HERE>>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----`;

function authoriseToken(req, res, next) {
  const token = req.headers.authorization;

  // If there is no token user is not logged in
  if (!token || token.length === 0) {
    next();
    return;
  }

  // If there is a token then add it to the res
  const tokenCrop = token.replace('Bearer ', '');
  const decodedToken = jwt.verify(tokenCrop, pemCert, { algorithm: 'RS256' });
  const userId = decodedToken.sub.replace('auth0|', '');
  req.authUserId = userId;
  next();
}

module.exports = authoriseToken;
```