# UnauthorizedError: invalid algorithm - Node.js express-jwt

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, express-jwt

I', trying to authenticate a user, I can create a user and get the bearer but after that I added this code to authenticate and it keeps showing the following error once every few seconds:

```
UnauthorizedError: invalid algorithm
    at /mnt/c/Projects/myProject/node_modules/express-jwt/lib/index.js:105:22
    at /mnt/c/Projects/myProject/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:121:14
    at getSecret (/mnt/c/Projects/myProject/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:90:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as verify] (/mnt/c/Projects/myProject/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:94:10)
    at verifyToken (/mnt/c/Projects/myProject/node_modules/express-jwt/lib/index.js:103:13)
    at fn (/mnt/c/Projects/myProject/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:746:34)
    at /mnt/c/Projects/myProject/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:1213:16
    at /mnt/c/Projects/myProject/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:166:37
    at /mnt/c/Projects/myProject/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:706:43
    at /mnt/c/Projects/myProject/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:167:37
```

The code:

```
const express = require("express");
const { ApolloServer } = require("apollo-server-express");
const jwt = require("express-jwt");
const typeDefs = require("./settings/schema");
const resolvers = require("./settings/resolvers");
const JWT_SECRET = require("./settings/constants");

const app = express();
const auth = jwt({
    secret: JWT_SECRET,
    credentialsRequired: false,
    algorithms: ['RS256'],
});

app.use(auth);

const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    playground: {
        endpoint: "/graphql",
    },
    context: ({ req }) => {
        const user = req.headers.user
            ? JSON.parse(req.headers.user)
            : req.user
            ? req.user
            : null;
        return { user };
    },
});

server.applyMiddleware({ app });

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("The server started on port " + PORT);
});
```

Can't figure out why 'RS256' is not a valid algorithm, should I need to require something else? Do I need different algorithms for different tasks?

constants.js contains the following:

```
const JWT_SECRET = "sdlkfoish23@#$dfdsknj23SD"; 

module.exports = JWT_SECRET;
```

Thanks

EDIT:

I'm not using Auth0, OAuth or any other service, I want to authenticate users by my own here

I'm registering a key when a new user is added to the DB (postgres) through the GraphQL API:

```
mutation {
  register(login: "john", password: "doe")
}
```

answers with:

```
{
  "data": {
    "register": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6NiwibG9naW4iOiJqb2VsIiwiaWF0IjoxNjE0NDM0NzMwLCJleHAiOjE2MTQ0MzQ5MTB9.ALltmClvlzxDJJ2FgZcFzstDUP5CY1xRzs8yQwheEn8"
  }
}
```

then I use this bearer like that:

```
// Headers
{
  "Authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6NiwibG9naW4iOiJqb2VsIiwiaWF0IjoxNjE0NDM0NzMwLCJleHAiOjE2MTQ0MzQ5MTB9.ALltmClvlzxDJJ2FgZcFzstDUP5CY1xRzs8yQwheEn8"
}

// Query
query {
  current {
    id,
    login
  }
}
```

I'm receiving this answer (also don't know why):

```
{
  "error": "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"
}
```

And the error at the top of this post on the terminal

Comment: I don't know if this causes the error message, but when you use an algorithm like RS256 (which is a valid choice), you can't just work with a random "JWT_SECRET", you need a proper key pair, the private key for signing and the public key for verification.

Comment: No clue at all where to put the public, I'm already generating a bearer through the register so It must be the public and the JWT_SECRET must be the private, isn't it?
i'll check the doc about express-jwt to see if it brings some light

Comment: RS256 have a special format. In this  [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53123467/cannot-verify-jwt-with-rs256-invalid-algorithm) you see an example how it looks like with private/public key pair. you can use an [online generator](https://travistidwell.com/jsencrypt/demo/) to create a key pair.

Comment: I'll try it, thanks

Comment: if I change the algorithms to add 'HS256' it works well, it's the RS256 which is not working  and still don't know why (I searched on the doc and so but....)

Answer (score 0):

For a bearer token with `JWT_SECRET`, use the `HS256` algorithm. The `RSA256` algorithm requires a public key and private key pair.

The following code snippet works:

```
const auth = jwt({
    secret: JWT_SECRET,
    credentialsRequired: false,
    algorithms: ['HS256']
});
```