# Verify JWT Signature (RS256) with public key on client-side, without a server/node.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwt, rs256

we are creating a front-end with react and need to verify a jwt (RS256) signature using a public key.

We have a .pem file which contains the public key like this

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
abc....
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

All examples we found are using node.js for this verification, is it possible at all verifying it on the client with no server involved?

We need to emulate the debugger in this page https://jwt.io/, where we have a jwt token and a public key, and verify if the signature is valid or not.

We can read the jwt without issues, but need to verify it's signature.

1. Is it possible?
2. If yes, is it right to do so on the client-side?

Thank you

Comment: take a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119043/verifying-auth0-jwt-throws-invalid-algorigthm - the npm packages should run client-side