# How to verify that Auth0 token was sent by correct application?

Tags: node.js, api, jwt, auth0

I am having a FE application that generates JWT token using Auth0. This token is then sent to my BE API. I am curious how to make sure that the token sent to my API was created by my FE application. I know I can check the `aud` claim, but AFAIK any application can set up any `audience` Auth0 just checks whether such API exists. So anyone in my organization can just fake the `audience` :(.

I was thinking about checking the `azp` claim, however, there does not seem to be support for this in the `jsonwebtoken` library.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: this has multiple answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119043/verifying-auth0-jwt-throws-invalid-algorigthm/71564958#71564958

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) does not have an option to check the `azp` claim, you can use the [callback](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#jwtverifytoken-secretorpublickey-options-callback) function to verify the claim yourself.

```
jwt.verify(token, 'shhhhh', function(err, decoded) {
   // Called after verifying signature, issuer, audience ...
   if (decoded.azp === 'FE_Client_ID') { 
        console.log('Validated !'); 
   }
   else {
        console.log('Invalid Client Id');
   }
});
```

Comment: that looks really promising I will have a look whether I can do something about it