# Tried to verify JWT signature by myself in nodejs to understand internal working of JWT, but decrypted signature gives wrong value

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, cryptography, rs256

To understand how digital signatures and JWT work, I tried to verify a JSON Web Token using RS256 algorithm. However, when I decrypt the signature part of a JWT it gives non-string values, so I cannot compare the value with the calculated hash value. Can someone tell me what part I am misunderstanding in my code? I used a RS256 algorithm JWT token, and all values are given in https://jwt.io/. If you scroll down and select RS256 option, you can get base64url encoded JWT and public/private keys. I guess that I am decrypting the wrong part of the JWT, but cannot find it out.

```
const base64url = require('base64url')
const crypto = require('crypto')
const fs = require('fs')

function readKeyPair(path) {
    return {
        publicKey: fs.readFileSync(path.publicPath),
        privateKey: fs.readFileSync(path.privatePath)
    }
}

function encryptWithPrivateKey(privateKey, message) {
    const bufferMessage = Buffer.from(message, 'utf8');
    return crypto.privateEncrypt(privateKey, bufferMessage)
}

function decryptWithPublicKey(publicKey, buffer) {
    return crypto.publicDecrypt(publicKey, buffer);
}

function hashMessage(message, algorithm) {
    const hash = crypto.createHash(algorithm);
    hash.update(message);
    const hashValue = hash.digest('hex')
    return hashValue;
}

const JWT = (
    'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZS' +
    'I6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWUsImlhdCI6MTUxNjIzOTAyMn0.POstGetfAytaZ' +
    'S82wHcjoTyoqhMyxXiWdR7Nn7A29DNSl0EiXLdwJ6xC6AfgZWF1bOsS_TuYI3OG85AmiExR' +
    'EkrS6tDfTQ2B3WXlrr-wp5AokiRbz3_oB4OxG-W9KcEEbDRcZc0nH3L7LzYptiy1PtAylQG' +
    'xHTWZXtGz4ht0bAecBgmpdgXMguEIcoqPJ1n3pIWk_dUZegpqx0Lka21H6XxUTxiy8Ocaar' +
    'A8zdnPUnV6AmNP3ecFawIFYdvJB_cm-GvpCSbr8G8y_Mllj8f4x9nBH8pQux89_6gUY618i' +
    'Yv7tuPWBFfEbLxtF2pZS6YC1aSfLQxeNe8djT9YjpvRZA'
)

const KEY_PAIR_PATH = {
    publicPath: 'rsa_pub.pem',
    privatePath: 'rsa_priv.pem'
}

const jwtParts = JWT.split('.')
const header = base64url.decode(jwtParts[0])
const payload = base64url.decode(jwtParts[1])
const signature = base64url.toBuffer(jwtParts[2])

console.log(header)
console.log(payload)
console.log(signature)

const keyPair = readKeyPair(KEY_PAIR_PATH)
const decryptedHashValue = decryptWithPublicKey(keyPair.publicKey, signature);

const newHash = hashMessage(jwtParts[0] + '.' + jwtParts[1], 'SHA256')
console.log()
console.log(decryptedHashValue.toString())
console.log()
console.log(newHash)
```

and this is output of the code

```
{"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"}
{"sub":"1234567890","name":"John Doe","admin":true,"iat":1516239022}
<Buffer 3c eb 2d 19 eb 5f 03 2b 5a 65 2f 36 c0 77 23 a1 3c a8 aa 13 32 c5 78 96 75 1e cd 9f b0 36 f4 33 52 97 41 22 5c b7 70 27 ac 42 e8 07 e0 65 61 75 6c eb ... 206 more bytes>

010     `�He �A����O��H7��Rb�'��!9���Ct�_S

8041fb8cba9e4f8cc1483790b05262841f27fdcb211bc039ddf8864374db5f53
```

Comment: this can be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119043/verifying-auth0-jwt-throws-invalid-algorigthm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The posted code UTF8 decodes the value of `decryptedHashValue`, corrupting the data and creating the gibberish. Arbitrary binary data such as ciphertexts or hash values must be converted to a string using a binary-to-text encoding, such as Base64 or hex encoding. Since `hashMessage()` hex encodes the data, hex encoding is the appropriate choice here:

```js
console.log(decryptedHashValue.toString('hex'))
```

which gives the following output:

```
3031300d0609608648016503040201050004208041fb8cba9e4f8cc1483790b05262841f27fdcb211bc039ddf8864374db5f53
```

This value can be split into the following two parts:

```
3031300d060960864801650304020105000420
```

and

```
8041fb8cba9e4f8cc1483790b05262841f27fdcb211bc039ddf8864374db5f53
```

The second portion corresponds exactly to the hash value `newHash` determined with `newHash()`. The first portion corresponds to the [digest ID of SHA-256](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8017#page-47), which is prepended in the case of PKCS1 v1.5 padding (RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5, s. [RFC8017](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8017)), the default padding used by [`privateEncrypt()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_privateencrypt_privatekey_buffer) and [`publicDecrypt()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_publicdecrypt_key_buffer).

However, I cannot reproduce the value you posted for the hash with the code you posted.

Comment: Thank you so much. Every example of hash gives viable string value for hash, so I though hash is just text. I didn't know that hash is binary. I spent about 3 to 4 hours and you saved my time. Thank you :D and for the different reproduction, I'll check tomorrow because it is currently midnight in Korea.

Comment: I pasted wrong hash value. The one you posted is right