# djangorestframework-simplejwt with auth0 - settings issue?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, auth0, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, rs256

environment:

- django (4.0.4)
- rest_framework (3.13.1)
- djangorestframework-simplejwt (5.2.0)

What are the exact [settings](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html) that should be used with simplejwt+auth0?
I cannot find any example and unfortunately i've failed to figure it out by myself.

I have tried the following:

```
AUTH0_DOMAIN = 'dev-demo-xxxx.auth0.com'
API_IDENTIFIER = 'xxxxx'
PUBLIC_KEY = None
JWT_ISSUER = None

if AUTH0_DOMAIN:
    jsonurl = request.urlopen('https://' + AUTH0_DOMAIN + '/.well-known/jwks.json')
    jwks = json.loads(jsonurl.read().decode('utf-8'))
    cert = '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n' + jwks['keys'][0]['x5c'][0] + '\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----'
    certificate = load_pem_x509_certificate(cert.encode('utf-8'), default_backend())
    PUBLIC_KEY = certificate.public_key()
    JWT_ISSUER = 'https://' + AUTH0_DOMAIN + '/'


SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ALGORITHM': 'RS256',
    'AUDIENCE': 'https://issuer-domain',
    'ISSUER': JWT_ISSUER,
    'VERIFYING_KEY': PUBLIC_KEY
}
```

but tokens that are sent from client (retrieved successfully using auth0 javascript library) are not verified properly on the backend. (token has been successfully verified using [jwt.io debugging tool](https://jwt.io/#debugger-io))

current error:

```
code: "token_not_valid"
detail: "Given token not valid for any token type"
```

Comment: verifying a RS256 token took me some time as well, shared a working solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71564958/8757883

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get Auth0 working with Django 4.1.3 and djangorestframework-simplejwt 5.2.2 using the configuration below.

The key areas that were tripping me up were the `USER_ID_FIELD` and `USER_ID_CLAIM` keys.

[`USER_ID_CLAIM`](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#user-id-claim) is the value that is inside the JWT. You can confirm what is in yours with a JWT [token debugger](https://token.dev/). Auth0 should include a `sub` field (for the unique user ID subclaim and should look like `auth0|1234..`), which is probably what you want to use for `USER_ID_CLAIM`. You can add additional data to the JWT with [custom claims](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/apis/scopes/sample-use-cases-scopes-and-claims#add-custom-claims-to-a-token), but I didn't go that far.

[`USER_ID_FIELD`](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#user-id-field) is the column in your database to correlate with the value that is received in `USER_ID_CLAIM`. In my case, I store the Auth0 user ID values in a `subclaim` column, so that's what I put.

```
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ALGORITHM': 'RS256',
    'AUDIENCE': API_IDENTIFIER,
    'ISSUER': f"https://{AUTH0_DOMAIN}/",
    'JWK_URL': f"https://{AUTH0_DOMAIN}/.well-known/jwks.json",
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'subclaim',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'sub',
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'JTI_CLAIM': None,
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': None,
}
```

Another note is that you can use the `JWK_URL` field to remove the need to manually parse out certificates, run the code under the `if AUTH0_DOMAIN:` block, or specify `VERIFYING_KEY`

Answer (score 1):

These are the settings which worked for me today:

```
AUTH0_DOMAIN = "YOUR_DOMAIN"
AUTH0_AUDIENCE = "YOUR_AUDIENCE"

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ALGORITHM': 'RS256',
    'AUDIENCE': AUTH0_AUDIENCE,
    'ISSUER': f"https://{AUTH0_DOMAIN}/",
    'JWK_URL': f"https://{AUTH0_DOMAIN}/.well-known/jwks.json",
    "USER_ID_CLAIM": f"{AUTH0_AUDIENCE}/email",
    'JTI_CLAIM': None,
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': None,
}
```

Dependencies:

```
django==3.2.15
djangorestframework==3.11.2
djangorestframework-simplejwt[crypto]==5.2.0
authlib==1.0.1
```

Comment: This worked for me. `JWK_URL` is a game changer, no need to deal with downloading the jwks and decoding the tokens manually.